# Extract columns from a number of variables to build a new variable in R

Tags: r

I loaded a bunch of CSV files into R. I have questions about how to extract the second column from the loaded data and create a new variable. I think I would like to know is there any function in R can 'append' extract rows into this new variable. My current code only keeps the second column from the last variable. Sorry for asking such basic operations.

Below is my R code:

```
filenames=dir() #Scan file names
 for (i in filenames){
  adt = substr(x = i, start = 1, stop = nchar(i)-4)
  name=paste("data_", adt, sep="")
  tmp <- read.csv(i, header=TRUE, sep=",")
  assign(name, tmp, pos=.GlobalEnv)  #save all the imported CSV content
  FB_d <- data.frame(cbind(tmp[,2]))  # I would like add the second column to a new variable, and I failed here...
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

## update

I tried `FB_d <- cbind(FB_d,tmp2[,1])`, but got error due to could find `'FB_d'`

Comment: If you have a csv already loaded you can say FB_d <- tmp[,2]

Comment: I would like to adding the second columns from different csvs into one variable. I think I am confused how to index it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would opt for something more like this:

```
write.csv(mtcars[1:5,],file = "~/Desktop/folder/file1.csv")
write.csv(mtcars[6:10,],file = "~/Desktop/folder/file2.csv")

setwd("~/Desktop/folder")

f <- list.files("~/Desktop/folder")

dat <- lapply(f,read.csv)
names(dat) <- paste0("data_",substr(f,1,nchar(f)-4))

do.call(cbind,lapply(dat,'[[',2))
```

i.e. use vectorization and list structures whenever possible. Also, I would (for the time being) banish `assign` from your vocabulary. It is an advanced function for very specifica uses in specific circumstances, and should not be commonly used for "ordinary" purposes.

I should also add a warning that `cbind`ing a large number of (large) columns will get quite slow fairly quickly, The solution to that problem is to initialize your data structure first (pre-allocate) and then assign into it.

Comment: Thanks! But for educational propose, is there a way to fix my code?

Comment: @tao.hong Well, I consider my answer the way to fix your code. ;) But if you insist, taking your update as a starting point, you would probably add an `if-then` clause that _creates_ `FB_d` on the first iteration of the `for` loop, and then `cbind`s to it after that.

Answer (score 0):

I like to load csv's using this method, if not particularly efficient:

```
fileList = list.files(path='path/to/files', pattern='xxxx.csv') 
FB_d <- vector()
dat<-lapply(fileList,read.csv,header=T,sep = "\t") #and then 
for(i in 1:length(dat)) {
  #do stuff here
  data_from_csv <- as.data.frame(dat[i])

  ##EDIT--adding to vector for each loop
  FB_d <- append(FB_d, data_from_csv[,2])

}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issue that `FB_d` is being overwritten each time through the `for` loop.

Comment: @joran: True. I now see what he is trying to do; store the variables from all tables column 2 in the same variable.